# What is the solution of the following equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

Here is the equation:

$${n\over x} + {\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {nx \over {( \lambda_i +x)\lambda_i}}} =0$$
for 
$\lambda_i>0, n>0$ and they are known.

I guess it has a reference solution, of which I am not aware.

I would greatly appreciate any hint.

UPDATE.
Assume **L** is the ${n}\times{n}$ Laplacian matrix of a simple, connected, non-bipartite graph. $\lambda_i, i=1,...,n-1$ are its non-zero eigenvalues and $\lambda_n=0$. To solve the aforementioned equation for particular (complete, star, path) graphs  should not pose a problem. However, to assign a meaningful graph-theoretical interpretation to *x*-s, a more general solution is requested. What I actually need is to find a function, ***g***, (or a meaningful approximation) such that $x=g(\lambda)$.

UPDATE 2.
Can this problem be reformulated in terms of integral equations?

Comment: I take it $n$ and the $\lambda_i$ are known, and you are asking to solve for $x$. But that will lead to an equation of degree $n-1$, so I wouldn't expect any general solution.

Comment: Yes, these (_n_ and _$\lambda_i$ are known, thank you.

Comment: Let us narrow the criteria assuming that $\lambda_i$ are non-zero eigenvalues of the ${n}\times{n}$ Laplacian matrix of a (connected, simple, non-bipartite) graph.
Can one thus outline some regularities of the solution?

Comment: Why don't you edit into the body of the question everything you know about the problem?

Comment: I supposed that to assign a meaningful graph-theoretical interpretation to x-s, a more general solution was required.